# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application leve

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5

Have tried to publish an MVC app through visual studio to an IIS server.

When trying to run it i am getting the error:

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 20:     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
Line 21:     <!---->
Line 22:     <authentication mode="Windows" />
Line 23:     <authorization>
Line 24:       <!--<deny users="?" />-->
```

there are a lot of articles around this but can't seem to work it out.

I have read that when deploying through visual studio it deploys it as a web app so no need to convert, well actually can't find the option to even do it.

The web.config is in the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\ and can't see any others in the views or other sub folders.

really stuck on this!

Comment: think i have gotten past it now